# How to get the difference between 2 cells

Tags: diff, microsoft-excel-2011, string

I have an Excel file like below.

- The value in column C should be the difference between A and B (A is always longer, B is always A substring).
- If both values in A and B are same, C will be empty.
- In C the substring (from cell B) should be replaced with a space.

The Excel file data example:

```
     A        |      B      |     C
example       | mpl         | exa e
example       | example     | (nothing, or ' ', doens't matter)
example       |             | example
example       | exam        | ple (or ' ple', doesn't matter)
example       | mple        | exa (or 'exa ', doesn't matter)
e x a m p     | x a         | e m p (or 'e  m p')
two words ex  | o words e   | tw x (or 'tw  x')
two words ex. | word        | two s ex. (or 'two  s ex.')
```

The Excel file has about 5000 lines and I don't want to make diffs manually.

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUBSTITUTE`:

`=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2," "),A2)`

(`IFERROR` is to manage situations when text from column B can't be found in column A text)

Comment: This assumes it will always be a single exact substring (as the sample data shows, so a fair assumption :) )

Comment: yes, I've assumed it based on the sample data:)

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks for solution, but it doesn't work (I maybe show short example data). String in A and B is multi-word, sorry, I haven't tell it you before. I update my question in a moment.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Edited the example code, hope it will be just any short update in your answer :-)

Comment: still in your examples you replace substrings (no matters whether they're multi-word or not, only matters, whether they are in the exact order in the original string), I've tested and it works. Please test my formula on your example. If it still not works on your real data, then please post more examples.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: hm, I tried it on my datas, and it works in a few lines. Now I see I gave you bad dataset (sorry, my fault, I see only a few first lines in my Excel), the separate words in B column can be from somewhere of A... `A: first second third fourth`, `B: first fourth` => `C: second third`. Both A and B contain more words, and now I see I can reformulate that as "replace all words from column B for a spaces and return the rest from A in C". Your solution above works, giving you +1, but please, if you know how to edit it, it will be great!